# Binary CSP instance

Tags: python-3.x, random, constraint-programming

Please am very new in python, and I am trying to do a Binary CSP instance, where it generates variables based on the number of variables the user wants. So if the user wants 4 variables, it generates X1, X2, X3, X4 and then appends to a list. I have tried working on it, still can't place it

```
class CSP:
    def __init__(self, variables):
        self.variables = list(variables)

    def get_variables(self):
        return self.variables

class Map(CSP):
    n = input("Enter number of variables: ")
    for i in range(n):
        vare = 'X' + 'i'

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self._collect_variables())

    def _collect_variables(self):
        variables = []
        variables.append(self.vare) #list the user appends to

def main():
    Map()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working for a simple reason: it **does not** generate several variables. Instead of it, it updates single variable 'vare'.

I should do it in the following way:

```
class Map(CSP):
    self._vare = []

    def __init__(self):
      n = input("Enter number of variables: ")
      for i in range(n):
        vare.append ('X' + 'i')

      super().__init__(self._get_variables())

    def _get_variables(self):
      return self._vare
```

Comment: @Iruoma Don't forget to mark the question as answered. Cheers!